# The ring $R$ that satisfying $x^n=x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Let $R$ be ring with unity such that every element $x\in R$ is potent ($x^n=x$, $n$ is fixed positive integer).

I know some properties of this ring like $R$ is commutative, $R$ has a finite characteristic, $R$ is reduced, and every prime ideal is maximal.

I need to write a project and I use these properties. My professor asked me to add a reference for them but I don't know the name of the paper that has these properties or the first author of them.

Does this ring has a name? after googling I found it is a special case of periodic ring.

Comment: Such a ring need not be periodic for $n=1$. So for fixed $n\ge 2$.

Comment: I thought that these *were* periodic rings, but after looking it up again I see that "periodic ring" means that the elements could have varying exponents with this property.  I don't think there's a more specific name for them than that. You could refer to such a ring as an "$n$-periodic ring."

Comment: Another extremely interesting property of these rings is that they are [von Neumann regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). Some of the nicest properties will come from this, so be sure to look into them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the reference for commutativity. If $x^n=x$ for all $x$ with some $n=n(x)$ depending on $x$, then $R$ is commutative. This was proved by Jacobson in [Structure Theory for Algebraic Algebras of Bounded Degree](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969205?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Later another proof was given by
Herstein in [power maps for rings](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1028998511).

More references: see the references at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29590/a-condition-that-implies-commutativity), and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32032/on-a-theorem-of-jacobson).